# Phone is rooted but can't pull files from /data/data folder

Tags: android, adb, root

My phone Samsung Galaxy S5 mini is rooted. I'm trying to pull files from `/data/data/myapp.package/` to folder on my PC.

```
adb pull /data/data/myapp.package E:\myapp\myapp.package
```

it gives me this error

```
adb: error: failed to copy '/data/data/myapp.package' to 'E:\myapp\myapp.package': Permission denied
```

I found many questions like mine but no answer solved my problem. Some suggested to execute this command `adb root` before pulling files. Some suggested to install **adbd insecure** app to enable root access. In fact after installing that app, phone disappeared from adb terminal. Both solution didn't work for me.

BTW, I can copy files using `cp` command from adb shell but I have to copy files to sdcard and then pull from sdcard. I'm looking for solution which allows me to copy files directly from `/data/data/myapp.package` to my PC

Any solution?

Comment: Actually you don't need rooted device if want to pull using ADB.

Comment: Sorry to say but You're wrong. Root permission is needed to pull anything from /data/ frolder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your adb to be able to access `/data/data` directly (for `adb pull`), your `adbd` should be running as root - which can generally be done by `adb root` command.

`adb root` would not work on commercial devices like Samsung Galaxy S5 mini as commercial devices have `ro.secure=1`, i.e., the adbd can't be restarted as root due to a check of property called `ro.secure`. **adbd insecure** app circumvents this and restarts adbd in root mode to enable `adb pull`, etc. to work.

In short, if **adbd insecure** app doesn't work for you, it's not possible to do `adb pull` from `/data/data` in your existing ROM. It might be possible if you change the ROM / do some boot.img tweaks, but I would probably suggest trying latest version / different versions of **adbd insecure** app before going for ROM changes.

[Read more on rooting here.](https://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-rooting-works-a-technical-explanation-of-the-android-rooting-process.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for that article too.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to hit these two command from command line

```
adb root
adb remount
```

then

```
adb pull /data/data/myapp.package E:\myapp\myapp.package
```

Comment: adb root is not working. it gives me no output and adb remount gives error "Not running as root. Try "adb root" first."

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner that lets you pull a file without installing anything else and without having to copy it to a public location on the device to then pull it to your computer:

```bash
adb shell su -c "cat /data/data/myapp.package/my_file.apk" > my_file.apk
```

What this does:

- `adb shell` runs a command printing the raw binary output
- `su -c` runs the provided command as root
- `cat <file>` prints out the file contents
- `> <file>` redirects the output from adb (i.e. the raw file contents) to a local file.

Answer (score 1):

This is my example pulling DB file from the root directory

```
adb -e shell "run-as com.example.project cp /data/data/com.example.project/databases/project.db /sdcard"
```

The key is `run-as`

Comment: this _only_ works with debuggable packages